# How can I protect myself from this crash *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, crash

The below code shows what I currently have, but a crash occurs on this line ' class = [mPageDataArray objectAtIndex:mPageIndex];'

```
  if (mPageIndex > mPageDataArray.count || mPageIndex < 0) 
  return;
  class = [mPageDataArray objectAtIndex:mPageIndex];
```

I don't know how else I can prevent the crash. Only one user experienced it and I am trying to make my App as crash free as possible.

Comment: `mPageDataArray.count-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do :

```
if (mPageIndex >= mPageDataArray.count || mPageIndex < 0) 
   return;
class = [mPageDataArray objectAtIndex:mPageIndex];
```

Because `count` is the total object in your array.
If there is 1 object, `count` will return 1, but the index to this object is 0

Here you crash, because you have 1 object in your array, but you are looking for something at the index 1 (which is the index for a second object)